# Cannot select iCloud in capabilities on tvOS

Tags: tvos

I have created an app ID with iCloud capabilities and selected my iCloud container for that app ID. I have also created and assigned the needed developer provisioning profile for the application.

My problem is that I cannot select "iCloud" under Capabilities in Xcode.
Any ideas what might be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least one physical device registered in xCode ?   If you don't have an actual appleTV, some of the features won't be available.  perhaps that link below the capabilities list can provide the exact reason for the 3 hidden capabilities.

Comment: Yes. [15 char limit]